# TS2742 -> The inferred type of 'consumerRunTimeHistogram' cannot be named

Tags: typescript, npm, typescript-typings

[I am using npm]

I am creating a package, prometheus, that depends on prom-client.

I have a package, queue-client, that uses this prometheus package. In the tsconfig of queue-client, I set declaration: true.

Now, in queue-client, i have this code

```
import { prometheusClient } from '@myorg/prometheus';

export const consumerRunTimeHistogram = new prometheusClient.Histogram({
  name: 'consumer_message_processing_time_seconds',
  help: 'Measures the amount of time in seconds it takes a consumer to process a message',
  labelNames: ['consumerName', 'messageStatus'],
});
```

I get an error
`error TS2742: The inferred type of 'consumerRunTimeHistogram' cannot be named without a reference to '@myorg/prometheus/node_modules/prom-client'. This is likely not portable. A type annotation is necessary.`

This error happens because we generate declaration files (.d.ts).

Now, if i set declaration to false in queue-client, everything works. But i dont want to do that, as queue-client is also a package made to be consumed.

What is 'best practice' here?

- I could go into my prometheus package and just export all types from prom-client ... or?

Comment: I think you should name prom-client as a peer dependency of prometheus anyhow.